# i am getting error with dependcies in apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, locale, cups-lpd

Whenever I try to install any package then following code is received:

further, if I am also trying to fix the dependencies it is also providing me an error.

*I have already tried installing locale using aptitude, I have tried editing /etc/environment for adding the locale variable*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bluez-cups : Depends: cups but it is not going to be installed
 hplip : Depends: cups (>= 1.1.20) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.24) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 printer-driver-gutenprint : Depends: cups (>= 1.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-hpcups : Depends: cups (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                  cupsddk but it is not installable
                         Depends: cups but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-splix : Depends: cups (>= 1.5.0-3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
himanshu@himanshu-HP:~$ sudo apt-get -f install        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups hplip printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-splix ubuntu-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 4443 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

i am having errors with dpkg also.

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

**all this is being seen after installing tools from katoolin**

output for locale -a is:

```
himanshu@himanshu-HP:~$ locale -a
The program 'locale' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install libc-bin
```

*and I can't install any package due to the brocken packages even with aptitude*

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add what the `locale -a` command outputs?

Comment: done,but i can't install any package using apt-get or aptitude

Comment: Ouch.. I think your system is severely broken, and that you should consider to reinstall it.

Comment: isn't there any solution

Comment: , can't I install locales via tarball

Comment: It seems to be the `libc-bin` package it complains about. Well, we are talking about the `glibc` source package, which provides some of the core things on your system. I for one don't know how it would be done. Maybe someone else does...